# Heroku app doesn't print the response i send to it, it only prints the console logs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to get my app to work with Heroku,
when I use my localhost it prints "Hello World" just fine with the below code, however when I put it on heroku it only prints the console logs I have and never shows the "Hello World" on my screen, when I go to my app:
https://serene-falls-66485.herokuapp.com/  it only says application error
and going to the logs doesn't help very much as well, no explanation there.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

[image: herokuDontshowhelloworld]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Heroku you need to bind to the `$PORT`.

Instead of `.listen(8080)` write `.listen(process.env.PORT | 8080)`

https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error